# how to parse xml file with logstach

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

this my logstash.conf :

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/path.xml"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "<test"
      negate => true
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
}

filter {
  xml {
    source => "message"
    store_xml => false
    xpath => [
      "//test/@no", "singletest_no",
      "//test/Barcode/text()", "barcode",
      "//test/Number/text()", "number"
    ]
  }
  
  mutate {
    gsub => [
      "message", "\t", "",     # Remove tabs
      "message", "\r", "",     # Remove carriage returns
      "message", "\n", ""      # Remove newlines
    ]
  }
  
  json {
    source => "message"
    target => "parsed_message"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "singletest"
    document_id => "%{singletest_no}"
  }
  
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

and this is the reslt i get : on kibana :

```
{
  "_index": "singletest",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "3",
  "_version": 5,
  "_score": 1,
  "_ignored": [
    "message.keyword"
  ],
  "_source": {
    "barcode": [
      "10io6G300"
    ],
    "result": [
      "PASS"
    ],
    "limit_exceeding_error": [
      "0"
    ],
    "tags": [
      "multiline",
      "_jsonparsefailure"
    ],
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2023-05-11",

    "message": "<Singletest no=\"3\"><Barcode>10io6G300</Barcode><Number>3</Number></Singletest>",
    
}
```

so what i want to do is to make message more structures i mean on this json form :
singletest_no : "",
barcode : "",
number : "",

how can i make this on config file i add the plugin json but it doesn't work . i want to put it in json format so if i want to send it to the frontend part it will be easy to consume the API
thanks in advance